# Single Batch script to open any editor/application in elevated administrator access

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, administrator, runas

I have been searching for ages now, for this.

All I want is exactly as I mentioned in my question, I have many editors like Sublime Text, VS Code etc.

But they all seem useless when it comes to edit Windows Hosts file, directly without closing them, in my Windows 7 64bit system.

So I want a single batch script to provide the same administrator access to the editor(whose executable's path I give in the batch script) as when editor is "Run As Administrator" from the context menu.

So that I can open the editor in elevated mode and also pass hosts file's path as an argument to open that as well. I have tried below code but in vain:

OpenWinHosts1.cmd:

```
@echo off
runas /profile /user:USERNAME "CMD /K \"C:\Path\to\OpenWinHosts2.cmd""
exit /b
```

OpenWinHosts2.cmd:

```
@echo off
start "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
exit /b
```

Can anyone assist in this ?

Comment: Don't mark it as duplicate unless you see it as absolutely same as other question, I already said it should be working in Windows 7 64bit and also it should open the hosts file directly with the same batch script, so these are two clear differences in my question. Please take a look at it again.

Comment: I'd carefully read the marked question Vicky. DavidPostill does not mark things duplicate by accident.

Comment: I have done that music2myear, but I still need a Windows Batch script based standard solution instead of symlinks and shortcuts, as batch script is more ideal, pluggable and developer has full control over it.

Comment: The Notepad/symlink solution is only when you're trying to open Notepad, and the answer at that question clearly states WHY you must run symlinks when doing this. Your answer is more likely to be the code in the question itself.